# Changing font color in categories

Tags: category, theme, code

I would like to change fonts on menu categories (Home  Shop  Lookbook)  and having a hard time finding the color in html.

http://siteground121.com/~mataano2/index.php/

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit file *megamenu.css* then change on line 120 this:

```
color: #363636;
```

with:

`color: yellow;`

Comment: you are amazing! Thank you. Kept going to style.css

Comment: one more question. How do I change the hover color that is orange and the black underline that comes under the menu icons when you hover? Thank YOu.

Comment: in custom_css_store_id_1.css on line 85 change color property of active class. For underline edit megamenu.css on line 26 and change border-bottom property as you prefer. Please vote this answer as useful.

Comment: To change hover color edit custom_css_store_id_1.css on line 7 and change color property.

Comment: i just joined today and i don't have enough reputation to vote. When I do i will come and vote. Thank you!